# blazor with MySql EntityFrameworkCore return output parameter get error

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

i am using MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore with blazor and when i want to get output value total count for pagination from store procedure i get below error

> Error: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): OUT or
>   INOUT argument 1 for routine get_articles is not a variable or NEW
>   pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger

below code is my store procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE get_articles(IN _offset INT, IN _count INT, OUT _total INT)
BEGIN
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * 
FROM content c JOIN content_types t 
ON c.content_type = t.id
WHERE t.name = 'article' 
LIMIT _offset, _count;
SET _total = FOUND_ROWS();
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

below code is c#

```
var totalCount = new MySqlParameter()
{
ParameterName = "@TotalCount",
Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output, 
};

var earningTypes1 = await dbContext.Result.FromSqlRaw(
"CALL get_articles (0,30,@TotalCount)",
totalCount
).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CommandType.StoredProcedure` instead of explicitly `CALL`ing the stored procedure:

```cs
using (var command = new MySqlCommand("get_articles", dbConnection))
{
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    var totalCount = new MySqlParameter()
    {
        ParameterName = "@TotalCount",
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Output, 
    };
    command.Parameters.Add(totalCount);

    using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
    {
        // build list from results
    }

    // use totalCount.Value...
}
```

Note that if you're using async DB operations, you'll want to make sure you're using [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) as your ADO.NET library and [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/) for EF.Core, as they're the only MySQL libraries that support async I/O.

Comment: is there is any way to pagination store procedure using MySql EntityFrameworkCore

Answer (score 0):

Since some versions of the Mysql connector do not support `out parameters`, the usual solution is to get the return value through `MySQL user variables`, and then use the query statement to get the variable value.

More details, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14586951/12884742).

Please confirm whether your current Mysql connector version supports the out parameter, you can refer to [it](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=25970).

Comment: is there is any way to pagination store procedure using MySql EntityFrameworkCore